# SqlAlchemy: create object if does not exist already?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm new to SQLAlchemy. I currently have:

```
ev = model.EnumerationValue(key=key_level_2, code=level_2)
ev.keyvalues[key_parent] = level_1
model.Session.add(ev)
```

How can I change this so it only adds the object if it doesn't already exist? This would be nice...

```
model.Session.create_if_does_not_exist(ev)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard pattern would appear to be:

```
ev = model.Session.query(model.EnumerationValue).filter(model.EnumerationValue.key==key_level_2).filter(model.EnumerationValue.code==level_2).count()
if not ev:
    ev = model.EnumerationValue(key=key_level_2, code=level_2)
    ev.keyvalues[key_parent] = level_1
    model.Session.add(ev)
```

Not terribly elegant (and I may have syntax errors - apologies) but does the job.

Comment: The approach seems correct, but I think the code is indeed broken. I have something locally that works, but it might not qualify as "The ONe True Solution".

Comment: Care to share your solution?

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something like the following

```
from sqlalchemy.exc import NoResultFound

try:
    ev = model.Session.query(model.EnumerationValue).filter(model.EnumerationValue.key==key_level_2).filter(model.EnumerationValue.code==level_2).one()
except ResultNotFound:
    ev = model.EnumerationValue(key=key_level_2, code=level_2)
    ev.keyvalues[key_parent] = level_1
    model.Session.add(ev)
```