# SQL select OR create if doesn't exist, using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

Using SQLAlchemy, is there a way to create a new entry with some set of values ONLY if an entry with that set of values doesn't already exist?

[One year ago nobody knew an elegant answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492623/sqlalchemy-create-object-if-does-not-exist-already). Does anyone now? The answer then given by [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415313/alex):

```
ev =    model.Session.query(model.EnumerationValue).filter(model.EnumerationValue.key==key_level_2).filter(model.EnumerationValue.code==level_2)
if not ev:
    ev = model.EnumerationValue(key=key_level_2, code=level_2)
    ev.keyvalues[key_parent] = level_1
    model.Session.add(ev)
```

Comment: there's probably no better solution because there's no standard SQL syntax that does quite what you describe.  Although there may be some RDBMSes that do have syntax for this; sqlalchemy mostly aims for what is standard or common;  You probably could extend sqlalchemy to use this vendor specific syntax; but for portable code, just use the accepted answer.